# current years in dropdown select box

Tags: php, date

I have this function for print current year in `select box` but `option value` not equal with `option text`. i.e :current years in selected `value` is 2013 but `html text output` is 2012. how to fix this?

PHP:

```
<select name="year">
    <?php
    for($i=date("Y")-5;$i<=date("Y");$i++) {
        $sel = ($i == date('Y')) ? 'selected' : '';
        echo "<option value=".$i." ".$sel.">".date("Y", mktime(0,0,0,0,1,$i))."</option>";
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Output:

```
<select name="year">
    <option value=2008 >2007</option>
    <option value=2009 >2008</option>
    <option value=2010 >2009</option>
    <option value=2011 >2010</option>
    <option value=2012 >2011</option>
    <option value=2013 selected>2012</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe not a good wayو But just Add `+1` for `$i`:

```
<select name="year">
    <?php
    for($i=date("Y")-5;$i<=date("Y");$i++) {
        $sel = ($i == date('Y')) ? 'selected' : '';
        echo "<option value=".$i." ".$sel.">".date("Y", mktime(0,0,0,0,1,$i+1))."</option>"; // change This Line
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Online Demo [Here](http://codepad.org/TaJChJuX)

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your value printing

```
<select name="year">
    <?php
    for($i=date("Y")-5;$i<=date("Y");$i++) {
        $sel = ($i == date('Y')) ? 'selected' : '';
        echo "<option value=".$i." ".$sel.">".$i."</option>";  // here I have changed      
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: I know! but I need to `date` function because I change date function for `Arabic date` with onother function. i.e: `arabicdate("Y", mktime(0,0,0,0,1,$i));`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
                $yearArray = range(2015, 2050);
                    ?>
                    Year
                    <select name="year" id="year">
                    <option value="">Select Year</option>
                    <?php
                    foreach ($yearArray as $year) {

                    $selected = ($year == 2017) ? 'selected' : '';
                    echo '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$year.'">'.$year.'</option>';
                    }
                    ?>
                    </select>
```

Comment: Its a static way to select the year

Comment: I think the asker wanted the current year selected in the drop down not a static choice of year.